# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1423 Field of view 'VIEW_NAME' underlying table doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm wondering what "**underlying table**" is referring to in the error below.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1423 Field of view 'VIEW_NAME' underlying table doesn't have a default value
```

I am aware of the issue where a field doesn't have a default value but here it is not clear what field is causing issues.

Comment: It's one of the tables being used in the view.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE VIEW VIEW_NAME;` will show the view's DDL where you may find all underlying tables names. Check columns of these tables which are defined as NOT NULL, primarily those ones which are not used in a view.